# May a monoid have two disjoint submonoids?

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

I'm asking this question inspired by the [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314882/may-a-group-have-two-disjoint-subgroups) about group and its subgroups. I tried to modify the proof presented there to work for monoids but I failed. I'm also not able to find any counterexample. So my question:

**May a monoid have two disjoint submonoids?**
or in other words:
**May a monoid have a different neutral element than its submonoid?**

If **YES**: Do you have an example of such structure?
If  **NO**: Can you prove it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"May a monoid have a different neutral element than its submonoid?"

By the very definition of a submonoid, no.

But of course there are sub-semigroups which happen to be monoids w.r.t. a different neutral element, for example $(\{0\},*,0)$ inside $(\{0,1\},*,1)$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $\mathbb N_0\times \mathbb N_0$ with componentwise multiplication. Then $\{\,(n,1)\mid n\in\mathbb N_0\,\}$ and $\{\,(n,0)\mid n\in\mathbb N_0\,\}$ are disjoint submonoids (with neutral elements $(1,1)$ and $(1,0)$, respectively).

In fact, simply consider $\{0,1\}$ with multiplication and the submonoids $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$.

Comment: I wouldn't agree that the second one is a submonoid. Since the neutral element of a monoid explicitly belongs to the algebra structure it must be contained in any subalgebra. On the other hand, it is a subsemigroup.

Comment: I guess it's just a matter of a different definition of a submonoid. I've been taught that submonoid is just a subset of a monoid which is itself a monoid. Without the requirement on the neutral element.

Comment: @Jeyekomon: Yes, it is. But note that your definition does not fit into the theory of universal algebra, which may have drawbacks. From that point of view you are not talking about a monoid, but just of a semigroup which accidentally happens to have a neutral element.

Comment: _"your definition does not fit into the theory of universal algebra"_ Could you possibly recommend something related to read? Or to look for? I'm not that advanced in math yet, but if there's a deeper reason to prefer your definition over mine, I'd love to understand it.

Comment: I could not recommend anything specific, but the Wikipedia page lists a lot of references. In particular this ebook (http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/ualg.html) looks good at first sight. One "deeper reason" to prefer this definition might be that there is a big general theory which applies to these kind of monoids as well as for groups, rings, vector spaces etc. There are many theorems which apply in a really big generality, and you don't have to prove them for any kind of algebra separately. One famous example is the fundamental theorem on homomorphisms.